# App Engine services not showing up under Cloud Endpoints and Dev Portal

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a php api service up on an app engine standard instance. I setup cloud endpoints pointing to the service without issues, however none of the service stats are recorded in endpoints > services, and the developer portal only displays "No APIs are available that you have permission to view."

I'm assuming there is some missing configuration. Google's documentation has left me at a loss for what I'm missing.

my app.yaml is simple:

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: auto
```

Is there anything that my app.yaml needs so that endpoints will pick up the api methods? I do have them defined correctly in the openapi.yaml swagger file and it validated with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Endpoints does not yet support App Engine Standard applications, with the exception of Python 2.7 and Java 8 for first generation runtimes using the ["Endpoints Frameworks"](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks).

So the simple answer is that your service is not actually using Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: So as of this morning I was actually able to get the dev portal to pick up my app engine standard services just by redeploying cloud endpoints. I'm now able to fully test my services using the dev portal without issues, so I'm confused when you say it's not supported on app engine standard. I guess I'm not clear on what the "Endpoints Framework" is and why it would be required. The only thing I did notice is that no matter how many times I call my app engine services, the stats do not reflect any activity in cloud endpoints. Not sure if I need to call some endpoint url directly or what.

Comment: To further support my comment about app engine standard being supported by cloud endpoints, in this google Next '17 video the presenter clearly states PHP, among others, is supported on app engine standard. https://youtu.be/bR9hEyZ9774?t=1388.

Comment: Yes, he states you can use PHP, but that is for App Engine Flexible. You can find the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#php).

Comment: I am a developer on Cloud Endpoints, and I know for a fact that Cloud Endpoints does not yet support App Engine Standard except for the Endpoints Frameworks. It does support App Engine Flex.

Comment: It's a shame that its not yet available. There are frustrating limitations in the standard environment. Doesn't work with Memorystore either I just discovered. I appreciate you taking the time to respond and will accept this as the answer.

Comment: There is an EAP starting for Cloud Endpoints on App Engine Standard; see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-endpoints/MnbLC95W1y4/nbmrUkVWBgAJ for more details.